# How do I check for IP address validity in a file?

Tags: file, perl

I have an information report in a text file, and I want to export them to CSV format and only for those lines that are in IPv4 format (by the first column). How do I do that in Perl?

```
10.10.10.1      10.10.11.11    51251    445      2019-03-05 11:59:29.008   29.156     ......
10.10.10.2      10.10.11.22    51234    123      2019-03-05 11:40:29.008   30.156     .A..SF
2001:288:8900:c400:2018:8ce:1ca8:9cb0                  2404:6800:4012:1::200e  62105    443 2019-03-04 23:59:32.458     0.340 17    ......   0        8     4763     1
2001:288:8001:c200:3171:3abcd:28af:7e8f                  2404:6800:4008:c04::bc  50286    443 2019-03-04 23:59:32.471     0.000 6     .A....   0        1       61     1
```

I only want to get the lines that are in IPv4 format as below,

```
10.10.10.1      10.10.11.11    51251    445      2019-03-05 11:59:29.008   29.156     ......
10.10.10.2      10.10.11.22    51234    123      2019-03-05 11:40:29.008   30.156     .A..SF
```

My code,

```
open my $fh, '<', 'in.txt';
open my $fo, '>', 'out.csv';
while (<$fh>) {
    next if ($. == 1);
    s/^\s+//;
    my $text = (join ',', (split /\s+/, $_))."\n";
        print $fo $text;
    }
```

How do I test if the first column is in IPv4 format?

Comment: I recommend using [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV) to write out the CSV lines so that any edge cases are handled nicely.

Answer (score 7):

[Regexp::Common](http://p3rl.org/Regexp::Common) contains the regex you need:

```
use feature qw{ say };
use Regexp::Common qw( net );

# ...
my @columns = split;
next unless $columns[0] =~ /$RE{net}{IPv4}/;
say {$fo} join ',', @columns;
```

Comment: [Available ones for `Regexp::Common::net`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::Common::net) (13).

Comment: @choroba,I try to use as you said ,but still can not work

Comment: use Regexp::Common qw( net );                                                                    open my $fh, '<', 'in.txt';
open my $fo, '>', 'out.csv';
while (<$fh>) {
   my @columns = split ' ';
   next unless $columns[0] =~ /$RE{net}{IPv4}/;
    say {$fo} join ',', @columns;
    }

Answer (score 2):

[Data::Validate::IP](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Validate::IP) can also solve this specific task.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Validate::IP 'is_ipv4';

...

next unless is_ipv4 $columns[0];
```